# Callbacks and events in python

Tags: python, events, callback, irc

I'm making a bot to link IRC and DC (direct connect) together.  There is an existing implementation in C++ I've been following, but it doesn't have all the feature's we're after.

I'm using an IRC library for python which is really well coded.  I can register some callback handlers for various IRC events (specifically receiving a public message).  This callback function is able to reference objects created in the main python execution from the thread within the IRC library.

Here are my callbacks:

```
def on_connect(connection, event):
    connection.join(ircSettings['channel'])

def on_disconnect(connection, event):
    sys.exit()

def on_pubmsg(connection, event):
    hubClient.sendMessage(event.source.split('!')[0] + ': ' + event.arguments[0])
```

And here's how I set them up:

```
# Create the IRC client
ircClient = irc.client.IRC()
try:
    ircConnection = ircClient.server().connect(ircSettings['server'], ircSettin$
except irc.client.ServerConnectionError, x:
    print x
    sys.exit()

# Set the IRC event handlers
ircConnection.add_global_handler("welcome", on_connect)
ircConnection.add_global_handler("pubmsg", on_pubmsg)
ircConnection.add_global_handler("disconnect", on_disconnect)
```

I really like this solution, as it makes for very tidy code (particularly in this example).  However, I have no idea how to modify my DC library to generate these events.

The main point of interest is the callback's ability to reference the hubClient, which is created in the main python program like so:

```
# Create the DC client
hubClient = DC.DirectConnect(dcSettings)
hubClient.connect(dcSettings['hub'])
```

Initially, I passed a function pointer to my DC library to run whenever a message is received:

```
def messageHandler(nick, msg):
    if nick is not ircSettings['nick']:
        ircConnection.privmsg(ircSettings['channel'], nick + ': ' + msg)

dcSettings = {
    'nick': 'dans_bot',
    'sharesize': 10*1024**3, # 10GB
    'ip': '0.0.0.0', # XXX: This might not matter, but needed for library
    'hub': ('192.168.1.129', 411),
    'handler': messageHandler
}
```

But I get the error:

```
NameError: global name 'ircConnection' is not defined
```

How can I set up my DC client to create a callback in a way that I can still reference these local (to the main execution) objects?

Edit: I added a declaration for 'ircConnection'.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `ircConnection` is a third party module. And a simple import of that module may solve this error of `global name`ircConnection`is not defined`. Try `import ircConnection` in your main module

Answer (score 0):

The only problem in your code is that the reference to `ircConnection` is first seen inside the `try-except` block and if it fails then the var will be None. Just write `ircConnection = None` before try.

```
# Create the IRC client
ircClient = irc.client.IRC()
ircConnection = None 
try:
    ircConnection = ircClient.server().connect(ircSettings['server'], ircSettin$
except irc.client.ServerConnectionError, x:
    print x
    sys.exit()

# Set the IRC event handlers
ircConnection.add_global_handler("welcome", on_connect)
ircConnection.add_global_handler("pubmsg", on_pubmsg)
ircConnection.add_global_handler("disconnect", on_disconnect)
```